# Trying to replicate a sql statement in pyspark, getting column not iterable

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

Using Pyspark to transform data a DataFrame. The old extract used this SQL line :

```sql
case when location_type = 'SUPPLIER' then SUBSTRING(location_id,1,length(location_id)-3)
```

I brought in the data and loaded it into a DF, then was trying to do the transform using:

```py
df = df.withColumn("location_id", F.when(df.location_type == "SUPPLIER",
                         F.substring(df.location_id, 1, length(df.location_id) - 3))
                         .otherwise(df.location_id))`
```

The `substring` method takes a int as the third argument but the `length()` method is giving a Column object. I had no luck trying to cast it and haven't found a method that would accept the Column. Also tried using the `expr()` wrapper but again could not make it work.

the supplier IDs look like 12345-01. The transform needs to strip the -01.

Comment: If you need to strip, maybe a better idea is to use `F.strip`? Replace the `F.substring(df.location_id, 1, length(df.location_id) - 3)` with `F.split(df.location_id, "-").getItem(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention it, you can use `expr` to be able to use `substring` with indices that come from other columns like this:

```py
df = df.withColumn("location_id",
    F.when(df.location_type == "SUPPLIER",
        F.expr("substring(location_id, 1, length(location_id) - 3)")
    ).otherwise(df.location_id)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how I was formatting it incorrectly, but this worked

Comment: Hi :) Can you accept the answer if your problem was solved?